# Pause command before Theorem shades the background black

Tags: beamer, pause

I'm using `\pause` command before a `Theorem` in beamer and below is the outcome. I updated MikTex, so my guess is that the update may have caused this, but not sure. Any help will be much appreciated, thank you.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\pause
\begin{theorem}
A theorem.
\end{theorem} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Update** The code works fine on Overleaf, but on my computer (I use MikTex with TexMaker) the problem is still present. It also persists with a few other themes as well, e.g. the theme `Warsaw`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide the code of a small *complete* document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`). Use the `edit` button left below your question, and paste the code of the sample document below the picture. Without knowing precisely your setup, it is impossible to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I've added the code.

Comment: It looks as if a fix has been found: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/654

Comment: Thank's a lot. You were right, it is fixed in release 3.61.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Ulrike Fischer, this bug has been fixed in beamer v3.61 or later

(see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/654 and https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/650 for details)

[image]

Comment: duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585824/pause-with-transparent-rounded-shadow-blocks-rendered-incorrectly