# \pause with transparent rounded shadow blocks rendered incorrectly

Tags: beamer, block, pause, rounded-corners, transparent

This simple LaTeX code is not rendered as one may expect.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{A first block}
    Something inside    
  \end{block}
  \pause
  \begin{definition}
    A nice definition
  \end{definition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It gives something like that when compiled with pdflatex.
[image]

When the `\pause` is removed it is render correctly as that.
[image]

The trouble also disappear if I remove the `rounded` aspect of blocks.

Is this a bug or did I miss something in the Beamer documentation?

Comment: miktex? And which engine?

Comment: pdflatex from texlive on Debian GNU/Linux.

Comment: then probably your beamer version is outdated.

Comment: Is `Document Class: beamer 2020/11/26 v3.60 A class for typesetting presentations` that outdated?.

Comment: yes, in this case there were a few bug fixes end of last year/begin this year. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578488/pause-command-before-theorem-shades-the-background-black